# Force.com IDE not seeing Triggers folder in new project

Tags: eclipse, ide, force.com-ide

I am trying to create a new Force.com IDE project to my production org and I do not see the folder for triggers and cannot seem to get any of my triggers pulled into here. What am I missing?

Below is my package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<version>38.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: Please share your `package.xml`.

Comment: Updated with package.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only load triggers from **[an edition that supports Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_packages_apex_ge_pe.htm)**.

If you want to *delete* triggers from a live org, you don't need to involve Eclipse. I typically use the Developer Workbench and a **[destructiveChanges.xml](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/daas_destructive_changes.htm)** file.

You have to actually include the triggers in your `package.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>
    <version>39.0</version>
</Package>
```

My typical package includes these types:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexComponent</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexPage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomLabel</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>StaticResource</name>
    </types>
    <version>39.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60072/discussion-between-adrian-larson-and-cmmoutes13).